# magento extension "remember me" not working

Tags: magento

I am using the [J2T Remember Me Checkbox](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2t-remember-me-checkbox.html) extension for magento.

Has anyone tried this extension? Actually its not working, although I have made all necessary changes and updation for it, and from magento site also I have noticed its not working for most of people so I just want to ask is there any other change which I need to make that is not described here in link? Or its really not working?

Please suggest or share your view.

Comment: sounds like a question you should be directing to the extension's developer.  If you have a question about customizing or extending it's functionality via programming, please rephrase.

Comment: I just want to confirm with whom have ever tried for this .. is it really not working?

Comment: you should tell us what magento version you're using: the only comment I see (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2t-design/extension/1709/j2t-remember-me-checkbox/reviews#reviews) it seems to work perfectly with v1.4

Comment: mine is also 1.4.0.1 but not working :( here are the comments with same problem -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/53200/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also needed the feature and couldn't get this extension to work. With a bit of googling I found a bunch of **really dumb** suggestions that involve storing the password, in plain text, directly in the cookie.

That was never going to do for anyone who is serious about running a business so I attempted [my own version](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/5039/clockworkgeek_rememberme) that is secure and works first time. It requires you to check and possibly alter the session lifetime in your server's PHP settings or alternatively edit `app/etc/local.xml` and change the `session_save` value from `files` to `db`.

Answer (score 1):

well I've just tried it, and cannot make it work. (v 1.4.0.1 also)

Follow Jonathan's advice, ask te developper